# Jasmine test case when a function is called in an if statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a function:

```
function getNames() {
        var ids = [];
        var checkAttr = function (array, attr, value) {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i][attr] === value) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var selected = result[i];
            if (checkAttr($scope.names, "name", selected.name) && ids.indexOf(selected.id) === -1 && selected.myInfo && selected.name !== "") {
                $scope.fundNames.push({
                    name: selected.name,
                    id: selected.id
                });
                ids.push(selected.id);
            }
        }
        ...
    }
```

I want to write a test that checks that I am using the checkAttr function to check both name and id to remove duplicates. But I am not sure how to. I tried using spyOn but kept getting errors.

I want something that reads like this:

```
it('should check the name and id to remove duplicates', function() {
   //do something here
});
```

Comment: You can only `spyOn` functions that are exposed as methods on an object that you have access to.  For instance if `myObj.myFunc` was a function, I could spy on it as `spyOn(myObj, 'myFunc')`.  As checkAttr is private inside of `getNames`, you can't gain direct access to it.

Comment: like @anied said, you can't spy on methods that are private.  Would you be able to give us a little more code to work with?  How exactly is `getNames` used?  And could it become  `$scope.getNames`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to mock that method without changing your code.

I think It would be a bad test if you could spy a private function. Usually your tests mustn't know about inner implementation of your functions because if you change inners you must change your tests. It's a bad practice. In your case you should test the function `getNames` like a black box by setting `$scope.names` and checking a result from `$scope.fundNames` after it's call.

But you can move `checkAttr` function outside and spyOn it to achieve your testcase.